# Не переходит в маршрут после проверки формата изображения

Tags: node.js, multer

Делаю проверку изобажений. Устновил `multer`, вот код конфига:

```
'use strict';

import multer, { memoryStorage } from 'multer';
import path from'path';

let storage = memoryStorage()
let upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1000000
    },
    fileFilter: (req, res, file) => {
        let ext = path.extname(file.originalname)
        if (ext !== '.png' && ext !== '.jpg' && ext && ext !== '.jpeg') {
            return res.status(422).json({
                errors: 'Only images are allowed'
            });
        }
    }
}).fields([{
        name: 'user_avatar',
        minCount: 1,
        maxCount: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'product_photos',
        minCount: 1,
        maxCount: 3
    }
]);

export default upload;
```

Расширения распознает, проверяет. Но после проверки он не переходит на мой маршрут, вот код:

```
import upload from'../config/multer.config.js';

router.post('/work', upload, (req, res) => {
    try {
        return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'API Its Working'
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(422).json({
            error: err
        });
    }
});
```

Почему не переходит в мой маршрут?

Comment: А файл сохраняется при этом?

Comment: Нет, так как он не переходит в мой маршрут

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `fileFilter` вызваться так, согласно [документации](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html):

```
   fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        let ext = path.extname(file.originalname)
        if (ext !== '.png' && ext !== '.jpg' && ext && ext !== '.jpeg') {
            cb(null, false); // отклоняем прием файла
        } else {
            cb(null, true); // принимаем файл
        }
    }
```

Comment: Что значит `cb`?

Comment: `cb` коллбэк функция, которую необходимо вызвать для дальнейшего действия с файлом, указав вторым аргументом `boolean` true если принимаем и false если отклоняем.